# Use php with cURL in phonegap app

Tags: php, html, curl, cordova

i have this code php with cURL and i need to show the result in my html5 app.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.taringa.net/top/posts/?fecha=3&cat=-1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$resultado = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

function parsear($i,$f,$s) {
list($crap,$y) = explode($i,$s,2); 
list($x,$shit) = explode($f,$y,2); 
return $x;
}

$topPostSemana = trim(strip_tags(parsear('class="icon points">','class="box sticky"',      $resultado),'<a><span>'));

$topPostSemana = explode('<span class="number-list">', $topPostSemana);
?>
```

How i show the result in html5? I use this but php doesnt work in my app with phonegap:

```
<ul>
    <?
    foreach ($topPostSemana as $post) {
        echo '<li><span class="number-list">'.$post.'</li>';
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

My example app: http://comercialposadas.com/mobile/app/

Comment: As it appears you know in the comment below, you know PhoneGap doesn't support PHP.  So instead, you're going to have to use javascript and AJAX to get the result from the website.

Comment: Thanks, I suspect that but i doesnt know how. Maybe you can help me

Answer (score 1):

whatever you want to do, just do it with JavaScript instead of PHP. That way, you can do it inside your PhoneGap application. You can for example use the [jQuery get()-method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) (which is a shorthand for jQuery ajax) to load the data from `http://www.taringa.net/top/posts/?fecha=3&cat=-1` and do your parsing with javascript.

rough outline:

```
$.get("http://www.taringa.net/top/posts/?fecha=3&cat=-1", function(data) {
  // parse data from http://www.taringa.net/

  ...

  // write results into HTML via JavaScript
});
```

Comment: Thanks vicious, i'll try your example. I never work that way. How i write my second code in javascript?

Comment: that depends on what you are trying to accomplish? `data` contains the contents of the url that was loaded so you can work with that. although i should note that due to Same origin Policy you probably won't be able the easily load data off that website - as it is stated on https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: With PHP and HTML works fine (http://comercialposadas.com/taringa/app/obenter-top-posts_taringa_ell-maty.php)

Comment: so just put that URL in the get method like in the example i gave you and grab the list with something like this: `var postList = $(data).find("ul");` Then you can do whatever you want with it, for example appending it to an html element (https://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Im very dumb with javascript. Like this?: `<script>
     $.get("http://comercialposadas.com/taringa/app/obenter-top-posts_taringa_ell-maty.php", function(data) {
      var postList = $(data).find("ul");     
     });
    </script>`

Comment: to be honest you won't make it very far with an html5 app if you can't write JavaScript/jQuery code.. i'm not gonna write the code for you so i suggest you start learning JS (http://learn.jquery.com/)